# XBEE S1 Wireless Connection

Tags: xbee

I have 2 Xbee S1 models, 2 Arduino Wireless Proto Shields, 2 Arduino Megas, and an Xbee Explorer and am trying to make one Arduino Trigger another Arduino to send a pulse, I have tried to set up many tutorials on youtube and digi, but still cannot get it to work.

Can someone walk me through the steps for setup?